# How do you clarify that something is not a metaphor in a poem?

Tags: creative-writing

How do you clarify that something is not a metaphor in a poem?

> There was a forest in the sky
>
> A beautiful green lush forest
>
> I could fly to it with my angel wings

How do you clarify that the forest is actually hovering in the sky and it's not a metaphor? In a poem or a novel?

Comment: I think a poem would be really hard, but in a novel, there's enough length and non-poetic writing that you should be taken literally when you discuss the character preening their feathers in the descriptions. I got nothing on the poem part, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Interpretation of prose is the province of the reader.

In prose, the more generic or general or abstract a description, the more likely it is to be interpreted by the reader as a metaphor.

The more specific and concrete the prose, the more likely it is to be interpreted literally.

Words like forest are generic and not specific. Pines trees is more specific, and *Populus tremuloides* is very specific — Aspen Trees.